# How to find the max of a given value and an address of a variable in assembly language?

Tags: assembly, arm, max, memory-address

I'm learning ARMv7, and the question is to implement this code:

```
shvar = max(shvar, x)
```

The value of variable x is R2, the address of shvar is in R1. My question is, is shvar essentially a pointer, and I need to "dereference" it, aka get the value it points to in memory?

I did something like that:

```
LDR    R3, [R1]
...
```

Side note: And my instructor said "Reading from memory again for a value you already have in R3 is not good", I'm wondering if he was referring to this.

Comment: There's not enough information here to go on, but yes if you have a pointer to a memory variable and you want use the variable's value, you load it through the pointer.  Once you've loaded it you have a copy that you can use to compare against or whatever.  You don't need to load it twice, so if you already have a copy no need to make another unless there's some chance it changed (e.g. by something you did).

Comment: In C, var names are automatically dereferenced to get the value in memory, except for array vars like `int arr[] = {...}`.  In asm, symbol names are just the address; you have to take care of loading from them.

Answer (score -1):

```
unsigned int max ( unsigned int, unsigned int );
unsigned int test ( void )
{
    return(max(4,5)+1);
}

00000000 <test>:
   0:   e92d4010    push    {r4, lr}
   4:   e3a01005    mov r1, #5
   8:   e3a00004    mov r0, #4
   c:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <max>
  10:   e2800001    add r0, r0, #1
  14:   e8bd8010    pop {r4, pc}
```

The calling convention is tied to a combination of the target (armv7-a) and the compiler authors choices.  Compilers can create/choose their own calling convention they do not have to conform to the recommended abi from the target vendor if the target vendor has an abi (which arm does).

The above is gcc, you can see that the first parameter being 32 bits (or less) goes into r0, the second r1.  And the result comes back in r0.

```
unsigned int max ( unsigned int *, unsigned int );
unsigned int test ( void )
{
    return(max((unsigned int *)4,5)+1);
}

00000000 <test>:
   0:   e92d4010    push    {r4, lr}
   4:   e3a01005    mov r1, #5
   8:   e3a00004    mov r0, #4
   c:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <max>
  10:   e2800001    add r0, r0, #1
  14:   e8bd8010    pop {r4, pc}
```

So no difference, bits is bits addresses, and such are notions of high level languages

```
unsigned int * test ( unsigned int *p )
{
    return(++p);
}

00000000 <test>:
   0:   e2800004    add r0, r0, #4
   4:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

It is only an address when used as an address for the few clocks where that means something then they go back to being bits.

```
unsigned int test ( unsigned int *p )
{
    return(*p);
}
00000000 <test>:
   0:   e5900000    ldr r0, [r0]
   4:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

For ARMs recommended calling convention r0-r3 are considered volatile, they have use on the way into the function, but the function does not have to preserve their state.  If it fits the return value goes back in r0.  So if that convention is used by the compiler you are using then r3 is perfectly valid.  But if it is not part of the return (unlikely if even possible) then you are welcome to do an

```
ldr r3,[r1]
```

but before your function returns then whatever you are using r3 for would want to fold back into the return or whatever the functionality is of the function.  So if you wanted to pass an address to say a benchmark you might do this

```
unsigned int test ( unsigned int timerregaddress, unsigned int numloops );
```

You could do something like this

```
ldr r2,[r0] @ read timer
loop:
   @ code under test
   subs r1,r1,#1
   bne loop

   ldr r3,[r0] @ read timer
   sub r0,r3,r2 @ compute difference in time
   bx lr
```

If the code under test does not use any of these registers (well almost whatever registers you use would need to be pushed and popped at the beginning and end of the function) then r2 and r3 would be the natural choice for intermediate variables.

I suspect the comment is related to code you did not show you probably re-used r3 losing the contents of whatever you had stored there with this load.

```
a = x + y;
a = 37 + z;
```

While the compiler might generate the first line, the second line destroys the contents in the variable a, same as doing

```
mov r3,#5
ldr r3,[r1]
```

So you would need to look at all of your code not the one line you sent us.